# How to spy on ServiceProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-module

### What

In my AngularJS app, I am trying to spy on some internals like `angular.module` and `serviceProvider`.

### How

I have succeeded in spying on `angular.module`

```
var moduleCalls = spyOn(angular, 'module').and.callThrough();
moduleCalls.calls.count() //-> 6
```

I have tried to spy on `angular.module(...).service` but it just seems like it was never called

```
var serviceCalls = spyOn(angular.module('MyApp'), 'service').and.callThrough();
serviceCalls.calls.count() //-> 0
```

or the more generic `.provider`

```
var serviceCalls = spyOn(angular.module('MyApp'), 'provider').and.callThrough();
```

### Why

At this point the use-case is hypothetical where I wish to be able to audit all user-defined components (like modules, factories, services, directives, controllers, etc) at the point of creation.

Along the same lines, is it possible to chain `and.callThrough()` and `and.callFake()` so that I can post to an audit log.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to spy on providers? And could you show the code that you have succeeded in spying on module?

Comment: @runTarm - I've updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

As `angular.module('myApp').service()` is actually just a shorthand to call the same method on `$provide` service. I think you could spy on those service registration methods like this:

```
angular.module('ng').config(function ($provide) {
    serviceCalls = spyOn($provide, 'service').and.callThrough();
});
```

I'm still not sure about where/when your app would call the `.service()` function but this might work in unit-test using `angular-mock.js`:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  module('myApp');

  module(function ($provide) {
    serviceCalls = spyOn($provide, 'service').and.callThrough();
});
```